# Problems with certificate validation on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and Cloudflare

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I am running a webserver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My CMS relies for updates on a site hosted with a Cloudflare certificate. My problem is that is started recently to be not accessible anymore.

When I connect via openssl s_client I get

> depth=1 C = US, ST = CA, L = San Francisco, O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", CN
>   = CloudFlare Inc ECC CA-2 verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

I manually installed the origin-ca certificates (ECC, RSA etc.) that are found on the Cloudflare support page — no change.

With Firefox (on windows) and openSUSE Tumbleweed and Leap 15.0 and 15.1 -> No problem site is loaded.

Could anyone help me which certificate is missing and how to install it?

Comment: As addon this is what tried already: Downgrade of openssl 1.1.0h to 1.0.2g, reinstallation of ca-certificates, installation of cloudflare origin certificates, installation of /etc/certs and /usr/share/ca-certifications directors from a suse tumbleweed, dto. from a freshly installed ubuntu 16.04LTS desktop

Comment: And, last but not least, I installed an ubuntu 16.04LTS in virtual box in the office and it works fine. As the ubuntu in question is a rented server for our website, I cannot "just reinstall" it. So I would really apreaciate some help finding the problem and removing it with the existing installation. Thank you.